# GeoIP Location data not coming in database and interaction object?

Tags: xdb, geo-location

I am trying to implement geo-location-based personalization for my website and for this, I would like to test the data locally.

I have enabled geolocation services from app-center and tested with the test page(see solution 3 from below link),
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498

the correct response is coming on above page.

I have also applied a patch referring below article which actually changes my local IP to a dummy IP and records are saving like this in the database.

[How can we work with Geo-IP in local instance?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16156/how-can-we-work-with-geo-ip-in-local-instance)

[image]

My Sitecore version is 9.0.2, as you can see all location fields are "N/A" apart from Ip address.

It's not working on any local instance of ours Although, our UAT instance is working fine with the location data, As on local instance service is working which is validated by test page.

Please suggest what we could be missing? 
In terms of firewall change mentioned here in solution 2

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/798498 
Can you please suggest what needs to be done for this?

OR there is some other configuration we should add if you have faced this issue as well.

please note as per other articles and Sitecore documentation we have all required configuration files enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There could be possible few solutions for this issue:

1. **Configure a Firewall** https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/setting-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html

```
geoIp-ces.cloud.sitecore.net

Discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net
```

2. **Use a Proxy server**: In Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config change the `Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader` setting to the value: `X-Forwarded-For`
3. This is a Sitecore bug so for `Sitecore 9.0.2`, download zip from here https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/azure-appgateways-and-sitecores-use-of-x-forwarded-for/ and apply in your `Sitecore`

Answer (score 0):

If your local system is inside a VPN network or company LAN then GEOIP will not work as it would be getting IP of VPN or LAN external IP rather than IP of your system.

You can write code to get IP of your system inside an aspx page and copy it inside Website folder.
You can test what IP you are getting for your system.It must be LAN/VPN IP instead of your local system IP.